# Button that change uitabbar item's image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I created a `UITabBarVontroller` with 3 tabbar items. I also set an image and a title for each item. In the first view (that correspond to the left item in the tab bar), I put a button that launch a method:
`-launchBtn()`

My aim is when I push the button I want to change number 2 item's image.

**NEW EDIT:**
I want to make that new image blinks(just one time) every time I launch the method.Any clue?

Comment: I hope my answer can help you

Comment: Another thing. I want to make that new image blinks(just one time) every time I launch the method.Any clue?

Comment: You can use: `dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0.3 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ });`. I'm changing my answer.

Comment: I changed my code in github

Comment: Please edit your question adding the blink thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
- (IBAction)launchBtn:(id)sender {
    // Retrieve UITabBarController
    UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window].rootViewController;

    // Get ViewControllers array
    NSArray *viewControllers = tabBarController.viewControllers;

    // Cast the ViewController you are interested and push the image when unselected 
    ((SecondViewController*)[viewControllers objectAtIndex:1]).tabBarItem.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"camera"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAutomatic];

    // Cast the ViewController you are interested and push the image when selected 
    ((SecondViewController*)[viewControllers objectAtIndex:1]).tabBarItem.selectedImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"camera"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAutomatic];

    // You can use this method to push the ViewController, too.
    //[tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];

    // Blink image
    [self blink:((SecondViewController*)[viewControllers objectAtIndex:1])];
}


// Blink image
- (void)blink: (SecondViewController*) viewControllers {

    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0.3 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // Cast the ViewController you are interested and push the image when unselected
        viewControllers.tabBarItem.image = nil;

        // Cast the ViewController you are interested and push the image when selected
        viewControllers.tabBarItem.selectedImage = nil;

        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0.3 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // Cast the ViewController you are interested and push the image when unselected
            viewControllers.tabBarItem.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"camera"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAutomatic];

            // Cast the ViewController you are interested and push the image when selected
            viewControllers.tabBarItem.selectedImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"camera"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAutomatic];
        });
    });
}
```

You can [download an example from here.](https://github.com/GabrielMassana/changeTabBarImage)